# Getting a floating div to stop upon reaching another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a floating `div` on the sidebar that scrolls with the page. Is there a way to add code that makes it stop when it reaches the footer?

See code in action: http://openbayou.staging.wpengine.com

jQuery code used to float `div`:

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function($) {

//this is the floating content
var $floatingbox = $('#one');

if($('#primary').length > 0){

    var bodyY = parseInt($('#primary').offset().top) - 20;
    var originalX = $floatingbox.css('margin-left');

    $(window).scroll(function () { 

        var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
        var isfixed = $floatingbox.css('position') == 'fixed';

        if($floatingbox.length > 0){

            $floatingbox.html();

            if ( scrollY > 1561 && !isfixed ) {
                $floatingbox.stop().css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 10,
                });
            } else if ( scrollY < 1561 && isfixed ) {
                $floatingbox.css({
                    position: 'relative',
                    top: 0,
                });
            }

        }

    });
}
});
```

Comment: This is not a WordPress question, and therefore is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Found a solution to my problem.

```
$(function () {
    var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
    if (!msie6) {
        var top = $('#one').offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function (event) {
            var y = $(this).scrollTop() + 20;
            if (y >= top) {
                $('#one').addClass('fixed');
            }
            else {
                $('#one').removeClass('fixed');
            }

            // don't overlap the footer - pull sidebar up using a negative margin
            footertotop = ($('#footer').position().top);
            scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop() + 760;
            difference = scrolltop - footertotop;
            if (scrolltop > footertotop) {
                $('#one').css('margin-top', 0 - difference);
            }

            else {
                $('#one').css('margin-top', 0);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What this does is it stops before the footer and I can configure the stopping point.

I appreciate all the help in solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the z-index of the sidebar behind the z-index of the footer?

**EDIT:** I didn't like the result of this so I went and made this work in jquery the way you want it...

try this for your scroll function:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
floatingbox = $("#one");
            if(floatingbox.length > 0){
                //get our current scroll position
                var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
                //get the position of the tag cloud relative to the document
                var contentY = ($("#sidebar .sidebar-tag-cloud").offset().top + $("#sidebar .sidebar-tag-cloud").outerHeight(false));
                //calculate the largest possible top margin size before it starts to overlap the footer
                var lastY = $("#footer").offset().top - $("#one").outerHeight(false);
                //check if our scroll location is past the bottom of the tag cloud
                if ( scrollY > contentY )
                {
                    //check if the current top position is less than the maximum position
                    if(floatingbox.offset().top<lastY)
                    {
                        //keep scrolling
                        floatingbox.stop().animate({"marginTop":scrollY-contentY});
                    }else
                    {
                        //check if we have scrolled back up and have a space at the top
                        if(scrollY<floatingbox.offset().top)
                        {
                            floatingbox.stop().animate({"marginTop":scrollY-contentY});
                        }else
                        {
                            // hard set to the maximum position
                            floatingbox.stop().css({"marginTop":lastY-contentY});
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
        });
```

I also made it a little more dynamic by getting the location of the bottom of the tag cloud and using that instead of your hard-coded number.

Comment: Didn't work. Keep in mind I'm not familiar with jQuery. Is there a way to add something to keep the div a certain pixels up when a user reaches the end of the page?

Comment: Hmm if you replace your scroll code with this code what does it do? That is to say what isn't working about it.

Comment: Nothing. Box doesn't scroll and css doesn't change. I've added the above code to the site so you can see.

Comment: Checked out. Looks like I forgot to copy paste setting the floatingbox variable. Made changes. Try that.

Comment: Still no go. Is there a way you can send a private message on stackoverflow?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I did find the problem... I didn't realize but you renamed the footer to: "two" if you rename it back to "footer" or replace all references to "footer" it works again.

Comment: Cool! Got it working however it continues to scroll over the footer. Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish - http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1447/. Was working on another solution but gave up and forgot to change the settings. Now I need to figure out how to get rid of the delay (animate) when scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after looking at your latest jsfiddle. I have modified that code to work with yours. http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/4430/ This will not have the animate lag and should work well for you.

```
$('#one').followTo('#two','#pointFive');
```

just replace #two with #footer and #pointFive with "#sidebar .sidebar-tag-cloud" and this should work in your code.